# Minification and build configurations in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, minify

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app. I'm trying to take advantage of the built-in minification features. Currently, I have the following in my web.config file:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
  ...
</system.web>
```

When I execute this, I notice the following in my HEAD section:

```
<link href="/Content/css?v=WMr-pvK-ldSbNXHT-cT0d9QF2pqi7sqz_4MtKl04wlw1" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/bundles/modernizr?v=jmdBhqkI3eMaPZJduAyIYBj7MpXrGd2ZqmHAOSNeYcg1"></script>
```

From what I can tell, this is a signal that bundling is working. However, it doesn't look like minification is working. I was expecting all of my HTML to be compressed. However, when I view the source, it appears neatly formatted. When I view the JavaScript, those files look minified. However, I was expecting the whitespace in the HTML to be removed as well. Is there something I'm not understanding?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundling and minification works only for scripts and styles. Use `IIS dynamic compression` for your pages.

- [Enable HTTP Compression of Dynamic Content (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753681%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

OR

- [Dynamic Compression in IIS 7](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/106947/Dynamic-Compression-in-IIS-7)

but it will only compress data (without minification)

Answer (score 1):

Only your JS and CSS will be minified and bundled. Your HTML will remain unchanged. Minifying HTML is less useful because HTML files are often *much* smaller than JS libraries.